# Rendering partial is just rendering string from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to render a partial from an ajax response.

```
//app/assets/javascript/pages/contact.js
$("#new_message").on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) { 
    $("#new_message").prepend("<%=j( render 'layouts/error_messages', object: f.object) %>")
});
```

This is sent from the message controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def contact
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.valid?
        ContactMailer.contact_me(@message)
        format.html { redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message was sent successfully.' }
        format.js { render nothing: true }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      else
        format.html { redirect_to contact_path }
        format.js { render nothing: true }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm guessing the problem comes from it not being in a partial, and I would have to send in the data in my format.js block.

When the ajax event is called it appends the string instead of rendering it

Edit* moving the code to contact.js.haml still makes it return as a string

```
$("#new_message").prepend("j(render partial:'layouts/error_messages', object: f.object))")
```

Comment: try renaming the file to `contact.js.erb` to ensure that the ERB tags will be interpreted correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
$("#new_message").prepend("#{ j(render partial:'layouts/error_messages', object: f.object)) }")
```

You might want to change the `f.object`

Comment: Awesome so I just need to figure out how to pull in the object to ajax

Comment: Thats easy, any instance variable initialized in the controller action will be available!

Comment: But it has to be declared as a local: {object: -variable-} not object ;)

Comment: When you say `{obj: @message}`, your partial will have the local variable `obj` and its content will be `@message`